# Get the number of the last "Heading 1"-Styled Paragraph above the cursor with VBA in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

For Example,

5. This is a Heading 1 Paragraph

   5.1. This is a Heading 2 Paragraph

   This is the text.

When the cursor is somewhere in "This is the text", I want to get 5 which is the number of the Heading1-styled paragraph on the top of it.

At the moment, I'm using

```
Dim myField As Field

Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF  ""Heading 1"" \n ")

       If myField.result = index Then
               ....
       End If
```

Although `myField.result` gets the number that I need, it also adds it to the text wherever the cursor is, which I don't want.

I need this number to compare it with an existing index in my code.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm still interested in what you need the information for - giving you an answer depends on knowing that, even if the question has been closed.

Comment: Why don't you read `myfield.Result` to get the number then delete the field?

Comment: @CindyMeister . What if the cursor is somewhere else and I want to get the heading1 number for a random paragraph in the document. I thought there might be another method to access this number only by giving the paragraph or its index (like ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Paragraph(10)) as an object.